# Error in variable shift in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In the example below, the first apply works.  The second throws "TypeError: ("Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'", u'occurred at index 0')"

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lag':[ 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3],
                   'A':[10,20,30,40,20,30,40,10,20,30,15,60,20,15],
                   'B':[11,21,31,41,21,31,41,11,21,31,15,61,21,25]})
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['A'].shift(x['lag'])[x.name], axis=1)
print df
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['B'].shift(x['lag'])[x.name], axis=1)
print df
```

Please tell me why this happens and how to fix it.
Thanks,

(Note: I do not have enough "points" to post a comment in [Variable shift in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523920/variable-shift-in-pandas))

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a tricky thing going on.  I'll try to be succinct.

When you are using `apply` with `axis=1` you are iterating row by row.  For each row, pandas handles it as a `pd.Series`.  After your initial assignment, you put `NaN` values in the `df`  When that row is accessed, the entire row gets interpreted as `float`

---

***work around # 1***
Ensure lag value is `int`

```
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['B'].shift(int(x['lag']))[x.name], axis=1)
```

***work around # 2***
Do assignments at same time

```
df = df.assign(
    C=df.apply(lambda x: df['A'].shift(x['lag'])[x.name], axis=1),
    D=df.apply(lambda x: df['B'].shift(int(x['lag']))[x.name], axis=1)
)
```

---

***better solution***
However, I'd use `numpy` to help with this

Those lags are just the current position values less the lag value

```
l = (np.arange(len(df)) - df.lag.values)
```

then

```
df['C'] = np.where(l >= 0, df.A.values[l], np.nan)
df['D'] = np.where(l >= 0, df.B.values[l], np.nan)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works like a champ!

Comment: @Bill I've got better in an update coming in a few minutes

Comment: That's crafty.  I assume this works a lot faster since it operates "column-wise" instead of 'row-wise')?

Comment: @Bill I added that answer to the question you referenced.  Go there and look at the time differences.  The speed up comes from not iterating over every row and instead using a vectorized approach of slicing.