# Shifting a pandas dataframe column by a variable value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    
Date        Value   shift_col
2021-02-11  50.12       0
2021-02-12  72.30       0
2021-02-15  81.87       1
2021-02-16  90.12       2
2021-02-17  91.31       3
2021-02-18  81.23       4
2021-02-19  73.45       6
2021-02-22  87.17       2
```

I want to shift the "Value" column by the value in the "shift_col" column.  The shift column can be any integer, including zero and can be sequential or not.

I've tried lots of different approaches. Just using "df.Value.shift(df.shift_col) doesn't work (it gives me an error of `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I've tried a few options from these posts:

- [Variable shift in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523920/variable-shift-in-pandas). - doesn't work for date based indexes
- [Pandas: Shift one column by other column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023685/pandas-shift-one-column-by-other-column-value) - seems to work but I really want to keep this pure pandas if possible with no other libraries.

This *should* be straightforward but it has me running around in circles chasing my own tail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't seem like you're actually trying to `shift` the array. You simply want to offset each value by a different positional amount right? Does this accomplish what you want:

```
# Create integer positions of each row
idx_positions = np.arange(len(df))

# "shift" those integer positions by the amount in shift col
shifted_idx_positions = idx_positions - df["shift_col"]

# get the label based index from our DatetimeIndex
shifted_loc_index = df.index[shifted_idx_positions]

# Retrieve the "shifted" values and assign them as a new column
df["shifted_Value"] = df.loc[shifted_loc_index, "Value"].values

print(df)
            Value  shift_col  shifted_Value
Date                                       
2021-02-11  50.12          0          50.12
2021-02-12  72.30          0          72.30
2021-02-15  81.87          1          72.30
2021-02-16  90.12          2          72.30
2021-02-17  91.31          3          72.30
2021-02-18  81.23          4          72.30
2021-02-19  73.45          6          50.12
2021-02-22  87.17          2          81.23
```

There is a corner case where the `shifted_idx_positions` might be out of bounds depending on your data. But, let me know if this is on the right track of what you wanted before I go any deeper into this.

Comment: You are correct.  I got so stuck on 'shift' that I didn't even look at other approaches.  This does exactly what I need. Note: I think it should be `df["shifted_Value"] = df.loc[shifted_loc_index, "Value"].values`

Comment: good catch on the code! I had originally named that variable something else and forgot to change it when I was done playing around.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It always helps to have another set of eyes look at a problem.